# Passing methods to Controller: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to pass a method to controller, in a project using Java 8, Spring and Hibernate. But I'm having problems with   "Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"  error.

My method from KomitentDAO looks like this

```
@Override
public int vratiBroj() {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    int num = 0;
    Query query = currentSession.createQuery("SELECT count(*) from 
Komitent"); 
    num = (int) query.getSingleResult();
    return num;
}
```

And Controller loks like this

```
@GetMapping("/dodaj")
public String prikaziForm(Model theModel) {

    Komitent komt = new Komitent(); 
    int a = komitentService.vratiBroj();
    komt.setSifra(a);   
    theModel.addAttribute("komitent", komt);

    return "komitent-form";
}
```

I need to set in komt.Sifra an Integer from my function. The query is just a test, it could be any other that return a single int. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way for querying databases and returning values to Model?

Comment: Does `komitentService.vratiBroj()` return a `Long`? If so: `int a = komitentService.vratiBroj().intValue();`

Comment: No, I return int everywhere. In my KomitentService is `public int vratiBroj();` and in my KomitentServiceImpl is                                                       `@Override
@Transactional
public int vratiBroj() {
return komitentDAO.vratiBroj();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

count(*) does returns Long not Integer.

So your method should look like:

```
public int vratiBroj() {
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = currentSession.createQuery("SELECT count(*) from Komitent"); 
    long num = (Long) query.getSingleResult();
    return num.intValue();
}
```